# SQL Server and Database Engine where server name is MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS

Tags: c#, sql-server

I connected to SSMS with parameters:

- Server name: `MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS`
- Authentication: Windows Authentication

and created a new database: `MY_DB`

I am using the connection string in my project (Visual Studio):

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="data source=MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=MY_DB; integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I created my project in Visual Studio and added a Data Connection with parameters:

- Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)
- Server name: MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS
- Authentication: Windows Authentication
- Connect to a database
- Select or enter a database name: MY_DB
- Test connection succeeded.

My project is of type: code first. When I run my project a new `.mdf` file is created (`myproject.mdf`) and this file is used as my database (I can see created tables). When I use SSMS, I can connect to `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

I do not understand, there is nothing about `LocalDb`, `MSSQLLocalDB` and `.mdf` file.

Do I have to use `.mdf` file? I want to use `MY_DB` database.

Answer (score 0):

*(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB* is not the same as *MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS*. You are creating your database in *MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS* but then you are looking in *(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB* and for obvious reasons you are not seeing your database. I personally despise these names because they are really confusing. You may read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition/)

**Solution**

Anyways, from SSMS connect to *MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS* and your database will be there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I realized that my explanation is not clear enough. I was using connection string with (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB when I started developing my application. I switched into  MY_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS now but database tables are being still creating in mdf file. I can see database tables in mdf file but I cannot see them in MY_DB. I do not understand what mistake I made.